# SSRS conditional on Date always show error

Tags: reporting-services, conditional-statements, ssrs-2012

I'm blocked because the conditional is evaluating both side of the statement:

=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!CancelDate.Value), Nothing, Fields!CancelDate.Value.ToLocalTime())

I'd like to have empty field when CancelDate has no value but because of the ToLocalTime(), it breaks.

Is there anyone who came across something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the local time conversion on a conditional statement like so:

```
=IIf(IsNothing(Fields!CancelDate.Value), Nothing, CDate(IIf(IsNothing(Fields!CancelDate.Value), Nothing, Fields!CancelDate.Value)).ToLocalTime())
```

This could probably by simplified, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing Nothing into " "

```
=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!CancelDate.Value), " ", Fields!CancelDate.Value.ToLocalTime())
```